# What does String() string exactly do?

Tags: go

Itried to read the documentation but I couldn't understand. Can you tell me what does it do in Go?

Function source: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder.String

Comment: A `strings.Builder` is used to build a string. `String()` returns that string.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that a method `String() string` is something Go'ish. It is not. It is just a method called `String` which returns a string.

Comment: Please share more details - what **exactly** didn't you understand about the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to incrementally build a new string, i.e. character per character. In order to do this efficiently many programming languages add the so-called string builders. This allows to essentially modify an array of characters rather than recreating a new string every time. Check the official example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var b strings.Builder
    for i := 3; i >= 1; i-- {
        fmt.Fprintf(&b, "%d...", i)
    }
    b.WriteString("ignition")
    fmt.Println(b.String())

}
```

String() is the last step when you convert that inner structure into the actual string. Try to play with the example above and assign builder to a string variable and you see that only works when you use String() method